# How can I unlock the selected channels in the Dope Sheet?

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I'm using the *Dope Sheet*. Could someone tell me if there is any way to lock and unlock many items at once, with one click?

I'm trying to select items with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

*1 see an example*:

[image]

[image]

But when I click unlock or lock, it does not affect all selected items.

*2 see an example*.

[image]

Can someone tell me if this is possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-select the channels on the left as you have been doing and then choose *Channel> Toggle Channel Setting> Protect*:

[image]

*Disable Channel Setting* and *Enable Channel Setting* also do this, disabling or enabling all the selected channels.

Comment: man thank you very much. I'll accept your answer but for now I can only vote up. while not pass the minimum time. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentality kept locking my channels when animating by pressing  <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and just realized all these bone can be locked and unlocked by pressing The  <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).